# Finding a subgroup of the Galois group of $E/(\mathbb{Z}/(p))$ where $E = (\mathbb{Z}/(p))(t)$, $t$ transcendental.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

As the title states, the setup is

Let $E = (\mathbb{Z}/(p))(t)$, and we are looking at it over $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ and $t$ is transcendental.

Let $G$ be a group of automorphisms of $E$ generated by $\sigma: t \to t+1$. Determine $F = Inv \, G$, and $[E:F]$.

Adjoining a transcendental element to a finite field is one of my weakest aspects of Galois theory, so I don't really know where to start. So $\sigma^p = id$, so $|G| = p$?

Answer (score 3):

As you have noticed, $\sigma^p=\operatorname{id}$, and clearly $\sigma$ is not identity, so $G$ has order $p$.

To calculate $[E:F]$ recall that the extension degree from the fixed field of the Galois group is always equal to the order of the group.

Finding $F$ shouldn't be too hard. Can you find a single nonconstant polynomial $P(t)$ such that $\sigma(P(t))=P(t)$?

Comment: So it looks like $t^p - t$ is fixed.

Comment: @user121937: Good (I was thinking about $t\cdot (t+1)\cdot\cdots\cdot (t+p-1)$, though). Now can you think of a polynomial $Q(X,Y)$ over ${\bf F}_p$ such that $Q(t,t^p-t)=0$?

Comment: $x^p - x - y = t^p - t - (t^p - t) = 0$

Comment: @user121937: So what's the degree $[{\bf F}_p(t):{\bf F}_p(t^p-t)]$ (note that $x^p-x-t^p+t$ is of prime degree $p$ over ${\bf F}_p(t^p-t)$, so it's irreducible)?

Comment: So then that is the minimal polynomial for the extension $\mathbb{F}_p(t)/\mathbb{F}_p(t^p - t)$, so it is degree $p$ extension? Suppose that for another polynomial $S(t)$, $\sigma(S(t)) = S(t)$. Then is $\mathbb{F}_p(t^p-t) = \mathbb{F}_p(S(t))?$

Comment: @user121937: You're correct about the first part (so the exercise is done, as I hope you see now?). About the second, the answer is no, for instance, if $S(t)=(t^p-t)^p$, then clearly ${\bf F}_p(S(t))\neq {\bf F}_p(t^p-t)$. If, however, the degree of $S(t)$ is $p$, then you have the equality by the same argument.